# ApiException: 10: Drive#SCOPE_FILE must be requested

Tags: android, google-api, google-drive-api

I am getting **ApiException**: 10. I tried looking over internet for this but found nothing. What is weird is that *I get this error on some devices and not on others*, ie, on some devices like emulator or my S7 the file is created but on some older devices it gives this error.

What I have checked: The Google play services are up to date on all devices running same version so I guess that can be ruled out.

**Code**:

```
    private void createNewFile(){
    final File file = getApplicationContext().getDatabasePath("eventManager");
    if(mDriveResourceClient!=null){
        Log.i(TAG,"Beginning Writing");
        final Task<DriveFolder> rootFolderTask = mDriveResourceClient.getRootFolder();
        final Task<DriveContents> createContentsTask = mDriveResourceClient.createContents();
        Tasks.whenAll(rootFolderTask, createContentsTask)
                .continueWithTask(new Continuation<Void, Task< DriveFile>>(){
                    @Override
                    public Task<DriveFile> then(Task<Void> task) throws Exception{
                        Log.i(TAG,"Writing task started");
                        DriveFolder parent = rootFolderTask.getResult();
                        DriveContents contents = createContentsTask.getResult();
                        OutputStream outputStream = contents.getOutputStream();
                        try{
                            InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
                            byte[] buf = new byte[4096];
                            int c;
                            while((c = inputStream.read(buf, 0, buf.length))>0){
                                outputStream.write(buf, 0, c);
                            }
                        }catch (Exception e) {
                            Log.i(TAG,"Writing task failed");

                        }finally {
                            outputStream.close();
                        }
                        MetadataChangeSet changeSet = new MetadataChangeSet.Builder()
                                .setTitle("My_File")
                                .setMimeType("application/x-sqlite3")
                                .setStarred(true)
                                .build();
                        Log.i(TAG,"Writing task started");
                        return mDriveResourceClient.createFile(parent, changeSet, contents);

                    }
                })
                .addOnSuccessListener(this,
                        new OnSuccessListener<DriveFile>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(DriveFile driveFile) {
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "File Saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        })
                .addOnFailureListener(this, new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Unable to create file", e);
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
    }
}
```

> **Error**:12-27 14:57:26.723 30393-30393/? E/MainActivity: Unable to create file
>                                                    com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 10: Drive#SCOPE_FILE must be requested
>                                                        at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbna.zza(Unknown Source)
>                                                        at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zze.zza(Unknown Source)
>                                                        at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zzbr.zzb(Unknown Source)
>                                                        at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zzbr.zza(Unknown Source)
>                                                        at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zzbp.handleMessage(Unknown Source)
>                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
>                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>                                                        at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)

Comment: have you solved this